# Custom class and ServiceProvider - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I try to make a new custom class in laravel 5.4 to check the user type.

I add this new class in a new folder app\ItSolution, code:

```
<?php

namespace App\ItSolution;

class DemoClass {


    public function getPermission() {
        switch(Auth::user()->user_type_id) {
            case 1:
                return 'admin';
                break;
            case 2:
                return 'promoter';
                break;
            case 3:
                return 'customer';
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this class in all my app , so i try to make a new ServiceProvider, code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App;

class AuthLibServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
       App::bind('democlass', function()
        {
            return new \App\ItSolution\DemoClass;
        });
    }
}
```

And i make a new facade for my class in the same folder app\ItSolution, code:

```
<?php

namespace App\ItSolution;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class DemoClassFacade extends Facade {
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'democlass'; }
}
```

After that i add this line in app/config.php

```
'aliases' => [
...
'DemoClass'=> App\ItSolution\DemoClassFacade::class,
]



'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Providers\AuthLibServiceProvider::class,
    ]
```

But i have this error when i try to use the DemoClass alias in my controller 
DemoClass::getPermission():

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DemoClass' not found

How can i fix that please, Thnaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel 5.4 you don't need a Service Provider to register a facade, you can use automatic Facadaes, you have to define only the DemoClass.

i.e in a controller:

```
use Facades\ {
   App\ItSolution\DemoClass
};
```

And call the function

```
DemoClass::getPermission()
```

Source [here](https://laravel-news.com/automatic-facades)

Answer (score 1):

You're registering this class as facade, so you'll need to add this to the beginning of the class:

```
use DemoClass;
```

Or you can just use full namespace when using the facade:

```
\DemoClass::
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's work, but have you any idea about how to use the facade in view ? Thank you.

Comment: @MalekBenelouafi I'm using helpers instead of facades, so I'm not 100% sure, but try to use it with full namespace `\DemoClass::`.